# Allowing a PFUser only one PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Im attempting to make it so that once the `PFUser` or the `client` creates a `PFObject` they cannot create/make one again.

Here I show how the `PFObject` is created:

```
-(IBAction)New:(id)sender
{
    PFObject *New = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"client"];
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    [New setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
    [New setObject:[[self Name] text] forKey:@"name"];
    [New setObject:[[self Team] text] forKey:@"team"];
    [New setObject:[[self Points] text] forKey:@"points"];
    [New setObject:[[self Height] text] forKey:@"height"];
    [New setObject:[[self Weight] text] forKey:@"weight"];
    [New setObject:[[self Position] text] forKey:@"position"];
    [New setObject:[[self Game] text] forKey:@"game"];
    [New setObject:[[self Hometown] text] forKey:@"hometown"];
    [New setObject:[[self Birthday] text] forKey:@"birthday"];
  //  [New setObject:[[self Bio] text] forKey:@"bio"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(PlayerImage.image, 0.8);
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", Name.text];
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:filename data:imageData];
    [New setObject:imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];

    [New saveInBackground];
    NSLog(@"Object Added");
}
```

With this code the `PFObject` is added to the `PFUser`, now I need a way to make it so that the `User` can't create another `PFObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement this with a Cloud Function.

- [Cloud Functions](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions)
- [Calling Cloud Functions in iOS](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#cloudfunctions/iOS)

In your Cloud Function you can check if the User already has a `client` set, and either perform an update instead of add, or just return an error.

Sample Cloud code, no change needed in iOS, simply prevents saving the "client" if there's already one on the current user:

```
// returns an error if a client is already set on the user
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("client", function (request, response) {
    var user = request.user;
    user.fetch().then(function (user) {
        if (user.get("client")) {
            response.error("user already has a client record");
            return;
        } else {
            response.success();
            return;
        }
    }, function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});

// links the client to the user if the save was allowed
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("client", function (request, response) {
    var user = request.user;
    user.set("client", request.object);
    user.save().then(function () {
        response.success();
    },
    function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: How would I check to see if the PFObject `client` has been set? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Added code sample that shouldn't require any changes to your iOS code (except maybe some error handling).